# Want to change Checkout button text in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, web, woocommerce

continue to shipping button text and continue to payment button text
in website woocommerce checkout is there any solution for this pls help me
[SH1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW4w6.jpg)
[Sh2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfoKw.jpg)
My website
[Cosmeticsonlinehubb.pk](https://Cosmeticsonlinehubb.pk)

I have tried all plugins but still got not solution for this.

Comment: Looks like you're using multistep checkout or maybe your theme has a multistep checkout feature. Well, if you know how to customize a wordpress theme/plugin template using a child theme then first find the template which has those buttons then customize those template files using a child theme. If you don't know about child themes and customization you can learn from articles and youtube videos or hire a developer to do your job. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change by adding this code to your theme's `functions.php`

```
function my_custom_checkout_button_text() {
    return 'My Custom Text';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'my_custom_checkout_button_text' );
```

You have to change the value which obviously is the My Custom Text to whatever you want.

Friendly, George

Comment: Thanks it's works fine . Also can i change.  (Continue to payment) text ?